# Windchill REST API endpoint to fill BOM from file

Tags: ptc-windchill

We are developing an internal project to use the Windchill OData REST API to fill the eBOM for a given part. What we are trying to do here is to read data from another software we have to get the BOM info and send it to the part in windchill. But we cannot find an endpoint in `servlet/odata` to do it.

We guess the idea is to replicate the manual process. So we already know how to create, check out and check in a part. However we still cannot find an endpoint to modify the part and add the eBOM.

We know `PartList`, `PartListItem`, `GetPartStructure` in the PTC Product Management Domain. But these are `GET` endpoints and are only useful to retrieve data, including the BOM. But we cannot use them to modify the content.

Comment: As sukriti gupta mentioned could you please share any reference or how you are doing it for the get part and are you able to export it in an excel format via Rest-API?

Comment: @flyaround you need to handle the excel export by yourself after getting the data. For more information about the endpoints I mentioned in my question, you can look for them in the REST API manual. [This link](https://support.ptc.com/help/windchill_rest_services/r2.2/en/#page/windchill_rest_services/wccg_restaccessexamples_prodmgmt_action_getpartslist.html) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The endpoint to use is:
`POST` `/ProdMgmt/Parts('VR:wt.part.WTPart:xxxxxxxxx')/Uses`

The **body** of the request must contain:

```
{
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Unit": {
        "Value": "ea",
        "Display": "Each"
    },
    "TraceCode": {
        "Value": "0",
        "Display": "Untraced"
    },
    "Uses@odata.bind": "Parts('OR:wt.part.WTPart:yyyyyyyyy')"
}
```

Where `Uses@odata.bind` contains the ID of the part we want to link